# How to turn dictionary into a dataframe with only a subset of columns using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the following dictionary format into dataframe with no success. How can I do that using instance_score and feature_score in input as columns in a dataframe?

input

```
{'data': {'f_score': None,
  'instance_score': array([ 0.99999967, -0.37898901, -0.38409877, ...,  0.0470927 ,
         -0.07509494,  0.32273143]),
  'feature_score': array([1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])},
 'meta': {'data_type': 'time-series',
  'detr_type': 'line',
  'name': 'ad'}}
```

code

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(input)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `pd.DataFrame`, specifying a subset of the columns you want to keep:

```
pd.DataFrame(d['data'], columns=['instance_score', 'feature_score'])

   instance_score  feature_score
0        1.000000              1
1       -0.378989              0
2       -0.384099              0
3        0.047093              0
4       -0.075095              0
5        0.322731              0
```

Comment: Thank you. Will accept this as an answer in 8 minutes because of my user limits.

Comment: @ferrelwill No worries, this is a pretty solid answer but feel free to hold off an accepting if you want others the chance to answer as well.

Comment: Surely if this is the answer then a duplicate should exist. Very solid answer though +1

Comment: @RoadRunner it very likely is. I'm happy to take a slap on the wrist for that, sorry. I just felt the itch to write an answer.